# mysql procedure insertion use variable

Tags: mysql, variables, procedure

I have a question when making a insertion in mysql Procedure.

I used a local variable `IDnew` to get the (max(id) +1) from original table.

Then I want to insert it back with some specific information.

However, I failed as the new ID is not what I want after insertion.
What is being missed here?

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure proc_InsertStar(IN sname varchar(100), IN syear INT(11))

BEGIN
    declare IDnew varchar(255);
    select IDnew;                #line A
    select concat("nm",lpad(cast(max(replace(id,"nm","")+1)as char),7,'0')) into IDnew from stars;
    select IDnew;                #line B
    insert into moviedb.stars(id,name,birthYear) values(IDnew,sname, syear);

END
$$

DELIMITER ;

call proc_InsertStar("jaden smith", 1998);
select * from stars where name="jaden smith";  #line C
```

The outcome is shown below:

```
line A: 
   [enter image description here][1]


line B:
[enter image description here][2]

line C:
[enter image description here][3]
```

However, the max Id should be 'nm9423081' which is 'nm9423080' add one on the lowest bit.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg7HF.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaHiZ.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzotC.png
```

Comment: `I used a local variable IDnew to get the (max(id) +1) from original table.` But why do you do this? It sounds like a terrible idea to me :-(

Comment: Really? Is there a better way? I just want to make an increment on the id...so I use that...

Comment: Just have an auto-incrementing id like everybody else. Job done.

Comment: Custom autoincrement implementations aren't as simple as you might think due to concurrency problems. However - You should post sample data and focus on your SELECT statement. We don't need to see the full SP.

Comment: Okay, I give up this dead end. As the assignment forbid us changing the table schemas, I'm going to modify the id in my java servlet. However I am still curious about the reason of this situation. Hope one day I can learn why!

Comment: @PaulSpiegel What do you mean by SP?

Comment: SP = stored procedure. BTW: I couldn't reproduce the issue (http://rextester.com/RWOKU37740).